# Call a function on each record from dapper result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dapper

I am trying to call a function on each record that will set some field values.  When the results are meant to be paged then this is achieved in the following way:

```
public IDataWrapper GetPagedQuery<T>(string myQuery, object param, Action<T> customAction)
{
    var obj = new DataWrapper ();
    using (var oConn = CreateConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        TotalPages totalRows = null;
        var list = oConn.Query<T, TotalPages, T>(myQuery, (e, t) =>
        {
            totalRows = t;
            if (mapAction != null) customAction(e);
            return e;
        }, param, splitOn: "SplitOn");
        obj.RowsFound = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)list;
        obj.TotalRows = totalRows == null ? 0 : totalRows.TotalRows;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

My problem comes when the results are not meant to be paged.  My query in the first example includes split on column and this is why it all works, however my next query is a simple query, such as `Select Column1, Column2 FROM MyAwesomeTable` which will return all rows, columns etc...

The problem is that I still need to apply customAction on each result that comes back.  Now lets imagine, that there is a potential of few million records coming back (believe me, this is not unrealistic given my situation), as such I do not want to loop through each record again aftermath and apply my method, I want that method applied as the dapper is returning results, just like it is in first case.

Here is what I tried:

```
public IDataWrapper GetNonPagedQuery<T>(string myQuery, object param, Action<T> customAction)
{
    var obj = new DataWrapper ();
    using (var oConn = CreateConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        var list = oConn.Query<T>(myQuery, (e) =>
        {
            if (mapAction != null) customAction(e);
            return e;
        }, param).ToList();
        obj.RowsFound = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)list;
        obj.TotalRows = list.Count();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I get an error for above code that it cannot resolve method `Query<T>(etc...`  I understand it is because it doesn't exist.  I am here asking what would be the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  Is it possible with dapper.

Comment: Your understanding of SplitOn is incorrect, its purpose is to map 1-1 complex entity and that has nothing to do with pagination, can be used with any kind of query. Current code which replace the TotalRows for every record, which would be same repetitive value fetched as Sql query is in itself not an optimum usage, though you can repeat for other part too with any number of records Also all the processing that dapper is doing is post getting data in the memory, you needn't be overly worried about traversing the data in the memory, if you have explicitly apply Action

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I believe I have a good understanding of SplitOn, the thing you can't see is my full SQL statement.  I might have done a bad job of explaining that part in the question and thus the misunderstanding.  All I was saying is that my pagination makes use of the spliton column as we are doing pagination with query, not that pagination has spliton.  Long story short, first query uses SplitOn, second doesn't.  Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Understand my point differently, you are using Func provided for the SplitOn to apply the Custom Action and in fact even in Spliton, it's filling the repetitive value, both are not correct. It was under the impression, that it doesn't need to traverse through the collection to do so, when Dapper is actually traversing through in memory collection as it is Linq 2 objects provider. Ideal way would be remove SplitOn everywhere, use instead QueryMultiple to get separate results in single call and then apply action separately as shown in the response that you have accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the short answer is that you can't do this.

The slightly longer answer is that in your paged query, it essentially *is* a second pass through the data since Dapper does some work to translate each row's data into an instance of "T" and then it makes a separate call to the "map" method that you use to call your "customAction".

So, there would be very little difference between that and doing a simple non-paged "conn.Query" call followed by a subsequent pass to execute your customAction. Something like the following:

```
public IDataWrapper GetNonPagedQuery<T>(string myQuery, object param, Action<T> customAction)
{
    var obj = new DataWrapper();
    using (var oConn = CreateConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        var results = oConn
            .Query<T>(myQuery)
            .ToList();
        obj.TotalRows = results.Count();
        obj.RowsFound = results
            .Select(value =>
            {
                customAction(value);
                return value;
            })
            .Cast<dynamic>();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

If your concern is that you may be loading many, many records in the non-paged query then it's worth bearing in mind that *all* of those records will be loaded into memory at once; they will not be pulled from the database one-at-a-time as your enumerate over the returned results and this might be a considerable drain on resources (if you're talking about so much data that you wanted to avoid a second enumeration).

This has to be the case because the SQL connection is closed as GetNonPagedQuery returns and so there is no way that it could be left open to read the data "on demand" by the caller. If you really are working with massive amounts of data, perhaps a non-paged query isn't the best approach?

*Note that in the code above, the "customAction" will only be called as you enumerate over the rows, those will not all be fired before GetNonPagedQuery returns. If "customAction" is potentially an expensive operation then this may be to you benefit. On the other hand, if you wanted "customAction" to be called for every result before GetNonPagedQuery returns then you would need one more ToList() call after the Cast<dynamic>(), it just depends which scenario is more useful to you.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert in paged query or non-paged query, but if anyone is looking to apply action for each rows, I've came up with this based on gbjbaanb's reference to Dapper documentation.

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> QueryLazyWithActionAsync<T>(this DbConnection self, string sql, object query, Action<T> action)
{
    using var reader = await self.ExecuteReaderAsync(sql, query);
    var parser = reader.GetRowParser<T>();
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        var row = parser(reader);
        action(row);
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

I use it like so

```
var result = dmsConnection.QueryLazyWithActionAsync<CustomerResult>(sql, query, row =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Querying for customer {row.FullName}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possibly is:

See the section of the Dapper docs about [Type Switching per Row](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#type-switching-per-row). I doubt (ie not tried it myself) that it wouldn't work if you used the same system to massage the results into the format you want by reading each row and processing it explicitly.

Comment: I've tried IDataReader.GetRowParser and it works. My use case is to report progress to Wpf UI.